# Parallel processing to create PDFs

Tags: c#, multithreading, pdf, itext

What I want to achieve is to do multitreading to generate invoices using iTextSharp assembly.

In my understanding in using `Parallel.ForEach` is that it will take an IEnumerable source and delegate that to different threads.

Now the issue that I have is that 1 process is trying to access a file that is being used by another process.

> *The process cannot access the file '...\Invoices\INV0000089576PPN.pdf' because it is being used by
>   another process.*

How can I prevent that from happening?

**Threading Process**

```
Task task = new Task(() =>
   {
      Parallel.ForEach(orders, currentOrder =>
      {
                LiveTrainingEntities db = new LiveTrainingEntities();
                var trans = db.Transactions.SingleOrDefault(x => x.fTransactionID == currentOrder.TransactionID);

                if (trans != null)
                {
                    var labOrderInvoices = GetLabOrderInvoices(trans.Practices.fPracticeID, currentOrder.TaxInvoiceNumber);
                    CreateLabOrderInvoice(PopulateHTML(labOrderInvoices), currentOrder.TaxInvoiceNumber);

                    Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", currentOrder.TaxInvoiceNumber,
                                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                    //orders.Remove(currentOrder);
       }
   });
});
task.Start();
task.Wait();
```

**PDF Method**

```
static void CreateLabOrderInvoice(string html, string invoiceNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            string strHtml = null;
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

            strHtml = html;

            string strFileShortName = invoiceNumber + ".pdf";
            string strFileName = @"~\Invoices\" + strFileShortName;
            iTextSharp.text.Document docWorkingDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 40, 40);
            StringReader srdDocToString = null;

            try
            {
                PdfWriter pdfWrite = default(PdfWriter);

                pdfWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(docWorkingDocument, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
                srdDocToString = new StringReader(strHtml);

                docWorkingDocument.Open();

                Image logo = Image.GetInstance(@"~\images\Image_PPNLOGO.jpg");
                logo.Alignment = Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;

                docWorkingDocument.AddTitle("Lab Order Invoice");
                docWorkingDocument.Add(logo);

                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWrite, docWorkingDocument, srdDocToString);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((docWorkingDocument != null))
                {
                    docWorkingDocument.Close();
                }
                if ((srdDocToString != null))
                {
                    srdDocToString.Close();
                    srdDocToString.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

**EDIT**
This is the Stack trace

> at ConsoleApplication1.Program.CreateLabOrderInvoice(String html,
>   String invoiceNumber) in ~\Program.cs:line 416 at
>   ConsoleApplication1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(order
>   currentOrder) in ~\Program.cs:line 70 at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass2d`2.<ForEachWorker>b__23(Int32
>   i) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__c()

Comment: Who is using that pdf? Is it another thread in the Parallel loop?

Comment: Do not do `throw ex;`, you are loosing the stack trace if you do. Either do `throw;` or not have the `catch` at all, you are allowed to have a `try` with a `finally` with no `catch`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, yes I think it might be another thread that might cause the issue

Comment: If so, why are you even accessing it in two threads? Why there is a collision? `invoiceNumber` isn't unique in the list?

Comment: What are you doing with that PDF with multiple threads? Only reading from it?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `PdfWriter` in his code suggests that he does a write :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I have made sure that there is no duplicate invoice number in the list and I still get the same issue. The ForEach should not hand it to another thread

Comment: Don't use the same tax invoice number on different orders, or create a partition per tax invoice number, or name your files something more unique than the discriminating only on the tax invoice number

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you generate a filename for a PDF, that you think is unique for a specific order, by using the value of the `currentOrder.TaxInvoiceNumber` field as the only unique discriminator.

However, as is clear from the error you get, it is not as unique as you think, and it seems that some orders have the same value for this field.

Your options:

1. Partition your data not only by orders, but by order / tax invoice number combination.
2. Use the combination of both ids (i.e. order id + tax invoice number) to generate the file name
3. Use a sequential Id + tax invoice number for the file name to ensure it is unique.

Comment: If thats the case, i suggest you to log the Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", currentOrder.TaxInvoiceNumber,
                                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); before the CreateLabOrderInvoice call. When you get the error in the output you may see the duplicated invoice

Comment: It has nothing to do with the uniqueness of the file name. It is the threads that are trying to access the same file name that causes that issue. I need a way to prevent that from happening